# Setting HTTP referrers for Google's geocoding web service

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I have a JS application that is reading a URL which contains a city and state and geocoding those values to obtain a latitude and longitude.  I am currently using the Google geocoding web service.

This works fine with no restrictions on my API key but since this is client side JS I am trying to set HTTP referrers with website restrictions.  When I add my site as an HTTP referrer

```
(https://*.mysite.com/*)
```

the application breaks.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=city,+state
```

The only error I get is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined
```

because I am not returning any data.

Do I have to do something additional to use this client side with http referrers?  I have no user input so I am trying not to use the Maps API since the google documentation says:

> The Maps JavaScript API provides a geocoder class for geocoding and reverse geocoding dynamically from user input. If instead you wish to geocode static, known addresses, see the Geocoding web service.

Answer (score 1):

The Geocoding Web Service is meant to be used server side, not from JavaScript.  You **have** to use IP Address restrictions on keys used with the web services.  If you want to use HTTP referrers, you need to use the Google Maps JavaScript  API v3.